How to build a OPC UA client for getting alarms from Siemens?
I am trying to build an Alarm status monitoring app for our workshop. And all our CNC machines have CNC controller, we have bought OPC UA server for them. But now I am not able to find any OPC UA client application that is free and that can store all alarm in an SQL server database so that it can be accessed later.
I have tried using OPC Foundations Github repository but I don't when I try to build it, many erros come for not able to find some DLL files. I don't know why they haven't put all files in there.
Does anyone know how to create a simple C# based client for collecting alarm records?
I have used apps like OPCUA Expert but their SDK has licensing and their free software just allows reading the tags and alarms, not storing it somewhere.

"How to build X" is usually to broad a question to be answered on SO. While it is a good idea include some background information, you should have a specific problem you need help with, like the build problem. If you are looking for libraries or other third party software, see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

first of all mark your Dbs in the siemens side, as OPC UA Accessible (sinumerik or tia portal) tutorial for tia portal
